# tMysqlRow syntax error

Tags: sql, etl, talend

I think my syntax error is the ";" char  both the queries because this component just accept one query.

Am I right?

So, what's the best practice in this case?

[image: Here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only execute a single query at a time in a single component.

Instead split the query into three distinct components that are chained together with OnSubJobOk or OnComponentOk.

Better yet, use some of Talend's power and move the logic out of the SQL statements there and into the components. You should be able to SELECT all of the data from your ta_ref_bi table with a tMySqlInput component and then link that with a main connector to a tMySqlOutput component that is set to `Drop table if exists and create` in the "Action on table".

Comment: Why would you MOVE the data out from the database, when you can move it INSIDE the database? In an input component you can use prequeries: I've used alter session to switch schema before executing the query.

Comment: It depends on the size of the data really but if it will fit into memory then there's very little overhead when literally pulling everything out of a table and dropping it back into another. If the source table has lots of constraints it may even be faster this way than the OP's original method but of course you could also have the database create a table without the constraints by properly specifying the create table statement rather than using like.

Comment: We're working with hundred thousands of rows :/ OP's should use a Shared connection for all these components. And yes it seems that talend can't handle well the database rows.